# Calling method reference using lambda (:: operator)

Tags: java, class, lambda, stream, method-reference

I have seen some approaches as shown below:

***calling like this:***

```
private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
  customerInput((bank, branchName, customerName, transaction) ->
      bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName, customerName, transaction));
}

private static void addCustomer() {
  customerInput((bank, branchName, customerName, transaction) ->
      bank.addCustomer(branchName, customerName, transaction));
}
```

***or using method references:***

```
private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
  customerInput(Bank::addCustomerTransaction);
}

private static void addCustomer() {
  customerInput(Bank::addCustomer);
}
```

I read that code like that: When calling `addCustomerTransaction()` method, it calls the `customerInput` method by passing `Bank` class's `addCustomer` method. But it seems to be a recursive call. SO, what is the meaning and could you pls give a brief example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `customerInput(Bank::addCustomerTransaction)` is basically translated to `(bank, branchName, customerName, transaction) -> bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName, customerName, transaction))` as they have the same signature. The catch is that the first parameter `bank` is the bank instance and `addCustomerTransaction(String branchName, String customerName, Transaction transcation)` (guessed the param types) actually has an implicit first `this` parameter which is the bank. So this method is different from the static `addCustomerTransaction()`.

Comment: Here's also a quick find for relevant topic that will hopefully explain different styles of lambdas and method references in Java: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-references-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: @Thomas Thanks a lot, but could not understand completely. Maybe my example is not a proper example. Could you pls explain by using a proper example as an answer?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Seems a useful page, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this won't be a recursive call since `Bank::addCustomerTransaction` won't refer to `private static void addCustomerTransaction()` but to a method with the same name and a fitting signature. I'll provide a simple answer but please look for a proper tutorial on this for details.

Let's assume the parameter for `customerInput()` is an interface that has a method like this:

```
void takeInput(Bank bank, String branchName, String customerName, Transaction transaction);
```

Now you could pass any method reference that matches this signature and the same method resolution rules apply that Java uses for normal method calls, i.e. if you have 2 methods `void foo(int x)` and `void foo(long x)` and a call `foo(2)` the compiler will need to determine whether you mean to call the 1st or 2nd method (here the 1st method would be chosen because `1` is an `int` literal).

*With those rules in place, how does the compiler select the method in your case?*

Let's assume we have the following class:

```
class Bank {
   void addCustomerTransaction(String branchName, String customerName, Transaction transaction) { ... }

   static void addCustomerTransaction() {
     customerInput(Bank::addCustomerTransaction);
   }
}
```

*Why isn't this a recursive call?*

Because `void addCustomerTransaction()` doesn't match the signature required for `void takeInput(Bank, String, String, Transaction)` at all.

*But why does the instance method `void addCustomerTransaction(String, String, Transaction)` match?*

That's because instance methods *implicitly* get a first parameter which is a reference to the instance (i.e. the `this` reference), so *to the compiler* that method looks like this (internally there is no difference between static and instance methods):

```
 void addCustomerTransaction(Bank, String, String, Transaction)
```

Now this matches the required signature and hence the method can be called.

To prove this, try to add a static method with the same signature:

```
 static void addCustomerTransaction(Bank bank, String branchName, String customerName, Transaction transaction) { ... }
```

Now the compiler can't decide whether to use the static method or the instance method and it will tell you so.

Comment: Thank you very much for these wonderful explanations. For further reading, could you please give me some reference tutorial so that I can read and make practice to get better idea.

Comment: And of course I would be grateful if you also vote up to the question

Comment: @Jonathan I find this article quite helpful and easy to read: https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-references But of course there are many others and you might need some experimentation to gain experience. Some more links: https://javadevcentral.com/default-method-resolution-rules, https://www.codementor.io/@eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx and a of couse the specification will help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12 (method resolution), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13 (method references)

Comment: **You rock!..** I will read all of them, thanks a lot again and regards...